# What to do about the solution explorer and getting around? Suggestions and improvements!

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I find the solution explorer is a bit slow to get around in sometimes, and think that there might be a better UI solution out there. I like Ctrl+T but sometimes a visual cue is better than remembering the class name?

I think it would be nice you had a second, similar window, that only shows files that have been opened during the current session? Any other suggestions

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upgrade your experience to the next level, you need to have Visual AssistX.
It enables links between your code and the files it comes from. And it's also light-weight. You will forget the Solution Explorer quite rapidly.

http://www.wholetomato.com

Answer (score 0):

In the toolbar's search box, you can type ">of ".  It will give you an intellisense-like dropdown of files in your solution as you type out the filename (e.g. ">of def" will show "default.aspx" and "default.aspx.vb" if those two files are in your solution).

I'm not sure if this any more/less cryptic than ctrl+t, but I thought I'd throw it out there.